# How to solve this problem? Using UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps in strict mode is not recommended and may indicate bugs in your code

Tags: reactjs

I read this problem and search it in google but can't get proper solution to sort out this problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.